# How to access data from a json list to build an Angular CDK data table

Tags: json, arraylist, angular5, angular-cdk

I'm building a couple of tables using Angular Material Design tables. I have manage to get the data from the json file an populate the tables. But the JSON file has some lists[], which I can't access from the html.

This is the code in my service to get data from the JSON file:

```
getReceiptAll(): Observable<ReceiptAll[]> {
return this.http.get<ReceiptAll[]>(this.serviceUrl)
```

}

This is the datasource in the component:

```
export class ReportDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
  constructor(private receiptService: ReceiptService) {
     super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<ReceiptAll[]> {
   return this.receiptService.getReceiptAll();
  }
  disconnect() {}
}
```

And this how I build the table in the html file:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
<!--* ID Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let receipt"> {{receipt.id}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
<!--* Period Start Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="receipt">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Date </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let receipt"> {{receipt.receipts.receivedDate}} </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

And this is part of the JSON file, as you can see the receipts are in an array and that is why is not possible to access the receivedDate using

receipt.receipts.receivedDate using the mat-cell tag in the html file.

```
[
```

{
    "companyName": "Acme",
    "documentType": "Standard",
    "receipts": [
      {
        "receivedDate": "2018-04-26T09:05:53.566Z",

I guess it could be something I should do in the service to access the content from the data to make it available in component DataSource, but I haven't figure it out what.

Any suggestions are appreciated.